# Update my existing datetime column to my respective timezone in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have  a table named "students" where student information are stored. Last week, I added a column (type-datetime) to keep track students last login time.

[image]

It was working well when  testing with localhost. So, I uploaded to hosting and after a few days, I noticed datetime are different with my local times. I called now() function in my code and it is inserting with server time (Seattle,USA Time). I tried to set it with my timezone.

```
SELECT @@session.time_zone;
SET time_zone = 'Asia/Rangoon';
SET time_zone = "+06:30";
SET @@session.time_zone = "+06:30";
```

although it is executed, it don't affect and inserting with server time like before.

My Question is **how should I update my existing datetime value column to my respective timezone. Thanks and appreciating.**

Comment: Best practise is to let server DB on server time zone but on returning return milliseconds and convert it to client timezone

Comment: Changing a session setting changes the setting for the given database connection only. You need to change the global setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach imho is to save all dates in UTC. Only at presentation time these times should be converted to the time and zone for the user.
Because you are using PHP, you can convert input into UTC and convert output to the desired timezone for presentation. 
This makes it also easy and possible to show foreign visitors their own time on your website.